# Singleton - Qual sua função e definição?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Dei uma pesquisada sobre, até vi alguns videos mas, não entendi muito bem a função ou até mesmo como ele funciona dentro da programação em Java.
Estou trabalhando em um projeto e um amigo me recomendou entender sobre Singleton para fazer a tela de login. Tem algum material legal pra me ler? Ou alguém consegue direcionar nesse assunto?

Answer (score 0):

Esse padrão permite que você crie um objeto único para a sua classe dentro de toda a sua aplicação.
Por exemplo, você utiliza a classe `Calendar` em vários lugares da sua aplicação, acessando sua instância através do método `getInstance()` do mesmo. Em todos os lugares que você está utilizando, a instância do `Calendar` é a mesma, você não dá um `new Calendar()`, você usa o `getInstance()` que é o método que faz o gerenciamento da unicidade do objeto.

Dessa maneira o padrão Singleton garante que uma classe tenha apenas uma instância na aplicação inteira, gerenciando-a de dentro da classe a fim de evitar que outra classe crie outra instância.

A vantagem é que o padrão Singleton pode ser instanciado e usada apenas quando necessário, diferentemente se criássemos uma variável global em que o objeto é sempre criado quando o aplicativo é inicializado e poderá estar usando recursos que não são necessários neste momento. O padrão Singleton define um ponto único de acesso global sendo inclusive muito mais fácil de gerenciar a criação e utilização da instância.

[Mais informações e implementação.](http://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-singleton-em-java/26392)